# MAMP Pro PHP not showing errors

Tags: php, mamp-pro

I am using MAMP Pro on my Mac which is great for development. I do have a problem though. It seems that MAMP Pro is very relaxed with my coding. If I make an error it just ignores it and continues to render the page without displaying any error messages.

This causes me problems when I push mods live as I then have to test again and rectify any issues in a live environment (not good!).

I have amended the php.ini file for the version of PHP I am using as per the following:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

This has not fixed the problem.

Anyone have any ideas?

Below are the MAMP PHP settings:
[image]

Comment: Check your code to make sure something in the code is not changing those values dynamically like `ini_set()` and `error_reporting()`

Comment: better logs errors in file, check the `log_errors = On` option and read the LOG file

Comment: Also make sure you can actually write to the file, I've had issue with that in the past. What happens when you do `error_log("test");`?

Comment: Give an example of an error that MAMP failed to report?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAMP Pro, you can set all the error logging and displaying of errors from the PHP Tab. Note the sections titled `What to log` and `Log errors`.

[image]

Once done, remember to restart MAMP so that the settings take affect.

Comment: I've amended my original post to include the screenshot of the PHP settings. I restarted the server and still no joy I am afraid.

Comment: Have you checked the `php_error.log` file as specified on the bottom of the PHP tab for errors? They may not be appearing on the page, but see if they are being logged to file.

Comment: Yes, checked the php_error.log file and nothing in there.